# Converting .tex file to pdf in Unix

Tags: pdf, sharelatex, unix

I edited my resume online using Share latex and tried converting the tex file to pdf in my mac command line 'xelatex resume.tex' command using the instructions mentioned in the github project below

https://github.com/leonz/resume-template

The problem that I am facing is with respect to the document class used online in share latex

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
```

for which I am not able to get source for.

So can someone help me on how do i achieve the conversion of .tex content from ShareLatex to pdf ?

Comment: The file `resume.tex` you link to doesn’t use `\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}`, it uses `\documentclass{resume}`.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @GuM I noticed it and i know i need to change to new document class in sharelatex which {letterpaper,11pt}{article} but i do not know how to get this file

Comment: `article` is part of the base latex release if you have latex at all you have that file, what exactly is your question?

Comment: When I executed 'xelatex resume.tex' I get the following error 
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.     Below are the first set of lines of my tex file which has \begin{document} 
  \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

Comment: Basically I am facing issues when i execute 'xelatex resume.tex' by copying the tex content from sharelatex editor

Comment: please add a small complete document to the question not to the comments (you can use the `{}` button in the editor to make a highlighted section as a code block. You will get a missing begin document error if there is any text (including invisible control characters) before the document. Paste an example that causes the problem.

Comment: The document you put in a comment does not give a missing begin document error but does give the error  `! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option pdftex` why are you specifying pdftex if you are using xetex?

Comment: Start compiling a minimal working example (MWE) as  `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}`  then add small parts of contents and the preamble that need that part (`xcolor` package if there are text in color, etc.), then  check that this still can be compiled. If not, analyze what is wrong with that  part. If you cannot discover the problem , take again the above MWE and add only the no problematic code and edit your question to show us the *complete* code.